Next SSR - Redirect to Same Page but with data
Trying to build something that does the following. I have a login page. If the login fails, I want to redirect to the same page but give an error message. I for the life of me cannot get anything working. Is there a way to redirect but also pass through some data?
'use server'

import { revalidatePath } from 'next/cache'
import { redirect } from 'next/navigation'
import { createClient } from 'utils/supabase/server'



export async function login() {
  const supabase = await createClient()

  const { data, error } = await supabase.auth.signInAnonymously()

  if (error) {
    redirect('/anonlogin');
  } else {
    revalidatePath('/', 'layout')
    redirect('/')
  }
}

import { login } from '@/anonlogin/actions'

import styles from '@/components/global/button.module.css'

export default function LoginPage() {

  return (
    <div>
      <form>
        <button className={styles.button} formAction={login}>Log in</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  )
}


You can use a return function

Why not use a Stateless option and go with a param i.e. redirect(/login?error=${encodeURIComponent(error.message)})
Then on the client-side useSearchParams#get('error'), then if you want to be fancy, you can mask the URL on the client-side and replace the URL in order to keep it clean.
